# Repeat function within itself

Tags: lua

Here is a sample code:

```
local function name()
  startingAction()
  if trigger() then
    endingAction()
    return true
  else
    resetAction()
    startingAction()
    if trigger() then
              endingAction()
      return true
    else
      resetAction()
      startingAction()
      if trigger() then
        endingAction()
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
```

Basically its a function that does something, but if in between it fails to do it, I would like to repeat this function by prefixing it with another action. The sample is 3 levels deep, but I would like to be able to control number of repeats.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you intending for `startingAction()` to occur after `resetAction()`?

Comment: If trigger fails (because startingAction didn't do it's thing correctly), then I have to do resetAction and do startingAction again (and if it fails again, repeat the process) (but in first step I assume, startingAction will do its job correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a basic [`while`](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.2.html) loop for this:

```
local MAX_RETRIES = 3

local
function name ()
   local tries_remaining = MAX_RETRIES

   while tries_remaining > 0 do
      startingAction()
      if trigger() then
         endingAction()
         return true
      end
      -- Implies else due to early return above.
      resetAction()
      tries_remaining = tries_remaining - 1
   end

   return false
end
```

If getting rid of the last `resetAction` call is necessary then you can modify the whole loop a little bit, although it is less readable and not-so-standardized:

```
local
function name2 ()
   local tries_remaining = MAX_RETRIES

   while true do
      startingAction()
      if trigger() then
         endingAction()
         return true
      end
      if tries_remaining > 0 then
         resetAction()
         tries_remaining = tries_remaining - 1
      else
         return false
      end
   end
end
```

Of course you can also do it with e.g. [numeric `for`](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html), labels or nice recursive calls. I'll leave these cases to you.

In general I encourage you to read [Lua Reference Manual - 3.3.4 - Control Structures](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.4) ff.